# No log information for the Starting Neo4j failed... issue

Tags: neo4j

I get the following error when trying to restart neo4j after adding a new procedure in the plugin folder:

> Starting Neo4j failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1d15704a' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.

My problem is not it failing to start (which i know is due to a flaw in my procedure plugin) but the lack of logs or messages suggesting what the issue may be.
It seems other people get some sort of error message: https://github.com/jbarrasa/neosemantics/issues/14

I have found two logs:

%appdata%\Neo4j Community Edition\logs

> 2017-05-25 09:20:03.840+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer] ========
>   Neo4j 3.1.3 ======== 2017-05-25 09:20:03.860+0000 INFO 
>   [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase] Starting... 2017-05-25
>   09:20:04.678+0000 INFO  [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt enabled on
>   localhost:7687.

..Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\logs

I wont paste this log unless requested as its long but there is only INFO lines and none of it looks interesting.

So is there anyway to turn logging on or am i missing a log that has info?
Developing will become a nightmare if every error forces me to keep manually testing each small change until i find the problem.

Comment: See https://neo4j.com/blog/user-defined-functions-neo4j-procedure-compiler/

also grep the logs on your package name, its easy to miss a needle in a hay stack

Comment: That link is perfect! Even better than i hoped for. Put it as an answer and i will mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See neo4j.com/blog/user-defined-functions-neo4j-procedure-compil‌​er also grep the logs on your package name, its easy to miss a needle in a hay stack